# Random image gets rotated when using picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I load different images in my RecyclerView and I use Picasso to get them from internet, but randomly an image from iPhone is getting rotated upside down and I don't understand why.
It looks fine on the internet.

my code is:

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(URLConstants.URL_BASE + imageURL)
            .placeholder(image)
            .error(image)
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    try {
                        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(URLConstants.URL_BASE + imageURL);
                        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
                        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                        if (orientation == 6) {
                            matrix.setRotate(90);
                        } else if (orientation == 3) {
                            matrix.setRotate(180);
                        } else if (orientation == 8) {
                            matrix.setRotate(270);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Bitmap oriented = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                            bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(oriented);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
```

I don't know if

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(URLConstants.URL_BASE + imageURL);
```

works with URLs or not.
And if they don't, what other way do I have?

Comment: From your code, you are setting an orientation from the variable value "int orientation". I think you should try loading the image without applying the orientation.

Comment: Try a simpler approach, Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);

Comment: why do u i think i tried the new way . the simpler way wasn't working

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan have you got any solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Right. This method will not work with URL.

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(URLConstants.URL_BASE + imageURL);
```

you should check this control on downloaded Bitmap.In this case it is not check downloaded one. You can save it like temp.jpeg. Beside It is the method in android ExifInterface.java, it says like that on comment.

```
/**
 * Reads Exif tags from the specified JPEG file.
 */
public ExifInterface(String filename) throws IOException {
    if (filename == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("filename cannot be null");
    }
    mFilename = filename;
    loadAttributes();
}
```

**Edited**

You can check this class for proper orientation https://github.com/eralpyucel/ProfileImage/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/eralp/profilephoto/PhotoFunctions.java

Comment: sorry for replying late . well i save the downloaded image in phone and yes it is stored in upside down position but my code still didn't pickup the orientation :/.